# Flask url_for not building base route with blueprints

Tags: flask

I currently have a route such as

```
@mod.route("/server/power/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/resize/<int:path>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@mod.route("/server/history/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/destroy/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def server(path=None):
# do stuff
    return "ok"
```

The problem is I'm trying to get the url_for to return this route upon being called

```
@mod.route("/server/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
```

But when I do this:

```
url_for('admin.server', path=server_id)
```

It returns the url for

```
@mod.route("/server/resize/<int:path>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

How do I get it to return the base route:

```
@mod.route("/server/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name specific routes, so by adding the `endpoint` to the route I was able to use `url_for` to the specific route

```
@mod.route("/server/power/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/resize/<int:path>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@mod.route("/server/history/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/destroy/<int:path>", methods=["GET"])
@mod.route("/server/<int:path>", methods=["GET"], endpoint='server_default')
@login_required
def server(path=None):
    return 'ok'
```

So when I called `url_for('admin.server_default', path=server_id)` it built the right url